# Android Auto application development

Tags: android, android-auto

I want to develop an android auto app.

I have installed android auto apk on my lollipop device and started desktop unit but on mobile screen after some steps and connecting the app to desktop head unit... only android auto is displaying on android device and desktop head unit on desktop showing **waiting for phone**.

How can I proceed to understand the prospect of desktop head unit android auto apk.

Steps I used while connecting

1. adb forward tcp:5277 tcp:5277
2. ./desktop-head-unit

[image: Android device apk]

Answer (score 4):

There's a missing step in the Android docs.

After enabling dev mode within Android Auto app, in the options menu in the top right corner (the same menu where you can turn on the head unit server), there's another option for "Developer Settings". Go there and then select "Application Mode" > Developer. This allowed ADB to successfully connect to my device by running `adb forward tcp:5277 tcp:5277` and then executing `./desktop-head-unit` (on mac osx)

Comment: That was it. I was stuck on a black "Waiting for phone..." screen. Also had to restart the head unit server on the phone. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the "Waiting for phone..." issue on a couple different devices. Here are the steps that worked for me. I am using DHU release 2.0.0 rc2.

- Open Android Auto app on your device.
- Get app in developer mode.
- Start head unit server
- Open the drawer menu in the app and tap "Exit
  App" **<--- important for successful connection**
- Run adb forward tcp:5277 tcp:5277
- Start DHU You should see the permissions screen on the mobile device now.

This behavior is seen due to issue in Android Auto App: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171130740

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine had the same thing.
When starting Android Auto Desktop Head Unit on his Windows 10 machine it kept saying "Waiting for Phone", even though the port forwarding seemed fine.
Tried multiple phones and ports, all working fine when connected to my own machine (similar setup).

Right clicking the Desktop Head Unit .exe and then choosing "Open as Administrator" eventually did the trick for us.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. You can try to change the port and again follow the steps like this:

Go to platform-tools directory and type : adb forward tcp:5999 tcp:5999

Use some different port number instead of 5277 like I used 5999. Once done go to auto directory and run desktop-head-unit.exe
Also, make sure your phone is unlocked while doing this.
It should work fine hopefully!

Answer (score 0):

When you use DHU on the Phone for the first time, the initial settings of the Android Auto app are required on the Phone, and the Android Auto app is automatically launched.
At that time, sometimes the Android Auto app is running in the background. Therefore, you need to bring up the Android Auto app from the task on the Phone and continue the setting. For example, swipe the Phone screen from bottom to top and select the Android Auto app from the task list to continue the initial setup.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to explicitly tell DHU to use port 5277 even it's default.

desktop-head-unit.exe --adb=5277